# W3 Schools image slideshow more than once on a page

Tags: javascript, html

I was using [this W3 image slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp) on my website. I wanted to use more than one, but if I try to add a second one, it doesn't work - the second one just displays as regular images on the next lines.

I tried changing the image class on both the js and HTML (after duplicating the js for the second slideshow), but that makes the first one stop working.

I can't seem to figure out how to make more than one slideshow work.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.r-button {
    color: #795548;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.l-button {
    color: #795548;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--
image sources (using images from online so it's visible):
https://www.pexels.com/photo/cash-coins-money-pattern-259165/
https://www.pexels.com/photo/silver-liberty-in-god-we-trust-1978-coin-64824/
https://www.pexels.com/photo/a-set-of-trampolines-in-a-park-4930675/
https://www.pexels.com/photo/raised-building-frame-169647/
https://www.pexels.com/photo/view-of-cityscape-325185/
https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-outdoor-pedestal-lamp-near-coaster-train-rail-92248/
-->
<div class="container">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259165/pexels-photo-259165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/64824/pexels-photo-64824.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px"> 
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4930675/pexels-photo-4930675.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
            <button class="l-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="r-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
        </div>
    
    <div class="container">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/169647/pexels-photo-169647.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325185/pexels-photo-325185.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px"> 
            <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/92248/pexels-photo-92248.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
            <button class="l-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="r-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
        </div>
```

It runs a little differently here for some reason, but still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must duplicate the functions and change the div class names they target.  Here's a quick example, just duplicating everything by adding 2 to the duplicated functions/elements (img class, prev/forward buttons, javascript functions that change the index and identify the container).

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
showDivs2(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function plusDivs2(n) {
    showDivs2(slideIndex += n);
}


function showDivs(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}

function showDivs2(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides2 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.r-button {
    color: #795548;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.l-button {
    color: #795548;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259165/pexels-photo-259165.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/64824/pexels-photo-64824.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px"> 
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4930675/pexels-photo-4930675.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
    <button class="l-button" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="r-button" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
    
<div class="container">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/169647/pexels-photo-169647.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325185/pexels-photo-325185.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px"> 
    <img class="mySlides2" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/92248/pexels-photo-92248.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" style="width:300px">
    <button class="l-button" onclick="plusDivs2(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="r-button" onclick="plusDivs2(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Christian! Thank you for the response. This seems to be working, apart from the fact that I'm having a problem where the second slideshow loads as images separate lines until I click the arrow buttons. Once the arrows are clicked, it is fixed, but it still loads like that every time. This happened to me before when I was originally using the first slideshow (before I put the second slideshow on the page), but it was fixed when I put the script source tag at the bottom of the HTML. However, I don't know what to do now since the script source tag is already at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I don't get it. The example is working, no?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. It works perfectly fine here, but when I put it on my website, the pictures load as if they've just been regularly added. It fixes itself upon clicking the arrow button, but reloading leads to the pictures loading oddly like that again.

Comment: Hi again. Turns out that I forgot to change one of the plusDivs to plusDivs2. That was entirely my own mistake, thank you for your help!!